# Windows 10: How do I change the path to a program to another location for a clean install?

Tags: installation, path, installation-path

I have a botched up modded game that I want to do a clean installation of on another drive. However, every time I run the installer, it points to the original installation folder. How can I trick it so I don't have to uninstall the modded version while being able to install it fresh somewhere else?
I tried looking around the registry to possibly change the path. But either I cannot find it or this isn't possible through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just opened the installer with a different windows user and I was able to get a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Did the installer ask you for the installation path the first time? if so then why not just uninstall it so you can change it since you are not going to use that one anyways? If you know the path you could also try moving the whole game's folder to the other drive directly if its not linked to a launcher or something like steam

Comment: The modded version is a mess but it is still a different experience than the vanilla. So having access to both the clean and modded version is ideal.